# Swift error: launch path not accessible

Tags: shell, swift

I'm doing a simple OSX App to show/hide hidden files in the Finder from a StatuBar menu.

This is the IBAction to show/hide files:

```
 @IBAction func menuClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.currentDirectoryPath = "/var/tmp/"

    task.launchPath = "usr/bin/defaults"

    if(sender.state == NSOnState){
        sender.state = NSOffState
        task.arguments = ["write", "com.apple.finder", "AppleShowAllFiles", "NO"]
    }else{
        sender.state = NSOnState
        task.arguments = ["write", "com.apple.finder", "AppleShowAllFiles", "YES"]
    }

    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()

    let killTask = NSTask()
    killTask.launchPath = "usr/bin/killall"
    killTask.arguments = ["Finder"]
    killTask.launch()
}
```

This gives me this error:

```
2015-05-10 23:54:22.237 ShowHideFiles[1234:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-05-10 23:54:22.238 ShowHideFiles[1234:303] launch path not accessible
```

I tried to find out why but cannot find an answer.

I tried also to see which of the two launchPath was wrong by disabling one or the other and they both give the same error.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Shouldn't the launch path begin with a slash? "/usr/bin/killall", "/usr/bin/defaults"

Comment: Yes!!!! That's the reason! Tks!!! (Place it as an answer so I can check it) ;D

Comment: Any idea why I can't run a program which is in the /Users/me/Downloads/ folder? I keep getting "launch path not accessible" although I can run anything inside /usr/bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `var` and `usr` are at the same level, so you need to prefix `usr` with `/` like you did for `var`:

```
task.currentDirectoryPath = "/var/tmp/"
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/defaults"
killTask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/killall"
```