# Why won't my application relaunch on other Macs?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm using this function below under a button to relaunch the application.

```
func relaunchApp() {    
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)
let path = url.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
task.arguments = [path]
task.launch()
exit(0) }
```

This works perfectly on my Macbook Air 2015 model. However, when I send this file to anybody else with the exact same model (or a Mac Mini I've also tried this on), nothing happens after the button is pressed. This is under both conditions of being completely compiled and just doing a run from Xcode, either work on my side. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `.absoluteString` is *not* the right method to create a path from an URL, it should be `.path`. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135305/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-fileexistsatpath-returns-false-instead-of-true.

Comment: Various security blocks too, depending on the OS version, security settings for the user, and whether the app/download has been started/opened before.

Comment: Function still worked on my side, but Airdropped this to the Mac Mini (macOS 10.11.6) and still nothing. @MartinR

Comment: Checked permissions on `/usr/bin/open`, and they were the exact same for each other. @dfd. Both are on same versions of macOS.

Comment: I'm not too involved with macOS (owned things since 1984 though) - but logic says (to me) that if a build works on one Mac but not the other, look into it. What if you **physically** installed the app on that MacMini?

Comment: The app isn't installed into the applications folder on here either, just in my Documents folder. I don't have those permissions. @dfd

Comment: Yes, but **how** is it installed? Via Xcode? or the HTML link? If the latter then I'm out of thoughts. Good luck, and please post an answer when you find it!

Comment: I airdropped it to the other device. It's just an application sitting in my documents folder. I'll be bountying this when i can, it's a bit important. @dfd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a `/` to the beginning of the `resourcepath` and using `path` rather than `absoluteString`.

```
func relaunchApp() {
     let fullUrl = "/" + Bundle.main.resourcePath!
     let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fullUrl)
     let path = url.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent().path
     let task = Process()
     task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
     task.arguments = [path]
     task.launch()
     exit(0) }
```

I discovered this issue when another function I'm using that directly opens a file `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Bluetooth.prefPane`, which while in Xcode outputted the following:

```
2016-12-09 11:51:56.749 Application[90077:1633677] launch path not accessible
```

Now, this function does work outside of Xcode but not within, and upon research of this error, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178117/5351192). Simply adding a forward slash and using the `path` rather than the `absoluteString` fixed the problem.

I'd like to thank @MartinR for mentioning the difference between `path` and `absoluteString`, @dfd, and @JWWalker for the help they provided.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a timing issue... if the `open` command runs before your app is fully gone, `open` may think it has nothing to do.  Anyway, your approach of using `open` seems unnecessarily complicated.  Try this (pardon my Objective-C, I don't know Swift):

```
NSError* err = nil;
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
    launchApplicationAtURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]]
    options: NSWorkspaceLaunchAsync | NSWorkspaceLaunchNewInstance
    configuration: nil
    error: &err ];
[NSApp terminate: NSApp];
```

Comment: eh, i can't really convert the async and new instance part.

Comment: I'll try adding a `dispatchQueue` for some set times and see which (if any) work.

Comment: What do you mean you can't convert the async and new instance part?  Anything that can be done in Objective-C can be done in Swift, no?  Or if you want to use `open`, you could try adding the `-n` flag.

Comment: I'm saying I can't convert this. I understand that anything possible in Swift is possible in Obj-C, I just don't know how to write this out in Swift. @JWWalker

Comment: Could my issue be due to the fact that there isn't a `/` in front of the resourcepath url? The output while in Xcode says 'Launch path not accessible', and a related issue under that name defines that the process is at the same level, requiring that extra /. @JWWalker

Comment: I don't know why there wouldn't be a slash at the start of `resourcePath`, because the docs say it returns a full pathname.  But instead of getting that and then stripping 2 path components from it, why not use `bundleURL` or `bundlePath`?

Comment: This actually did solve my issue, I'll drop the answer.